# Post modified by me, but it didn't mention me as modifier

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Something *weird* happened to me. I modified a question and the modifications applied, but the system didn't mention that the question was modified by me. It didn't even mention that the question was modified at all. Is this a bug?

[Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609424/all-css-variables-defined-but-result-not-usable-is-it-the-cascade)

Comment: Because your edit wasn't applied: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25018951

Comment: but this is not the edit that i suggested i suggested the snippet area

Comment: That's the remaining changes after Victoria's previous edit (which caused your edit to be rejected) has been applied. So you both changed the snippets, but only you also removed that sentence. So the system now "thinks" that you only removed that sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug.

You did suggest [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25018951) to that post, but your edit was automatically rejected by [the Community bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) because it "conflicted with a subsequent edit".

As such, your edit did not take effect, and you are not credited in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59609424/revisions) as one of the editors of that post.

Presumably, the author of the post ([Victoria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265955/victoria)) was still working on improving her question, and submitted her edit at nearly the same time as you did. The original author of a post has special privileges when it comes to edit conflicts, and their edit trumps yours.

Comment: what confused me that she made almost the exact same change that i made :/